# The intersection points of several Brillouin zones

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

The picture was a screenshot of the 2D Brillouin zone in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MJrb7xScbU&feature=youtu.be).

However, it was noticeable that there's many points where several different Brillouin zone intersects, as shown in the below picture. Those points seemed to have some sort of pattern that expand in circle of increasing radius, obviously from the symmetry of the construction.

Does those intersection points of several Brillouin zones have some special physical property?

[image]